# Eclipse 4.3 + WindowBuilder hangs while saving workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, save, freeze, windowbuilder

Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) with installed Plug-In WindowBuilder (from http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.3/).
Causes freeze while saving at ~ 60%.
Components used: JFrame, JLabel, JTextField, JButton, JTable(with Models), JTabbedPanel, JPanel.

If i only add 2 components and save it, then its no problem with saving, but if i adding more than 5 components then its freezing while saving. Aborting saving doesnt help.
So i press CTRL+Print to open my ScreenshotCapturer, to catch a screenshot then the saving is worked. Without the ScreenshotCapturer (my own written App in C#) i can't save my project in eclipse, because its freezed.

So i looked up in the workspace/.metadata/.log and found the NullPointerException that caused while saving:

> !MESSAGE Designer [1.6.0.r43x201305211944.201308211039]: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.AstEvaluationEngine$1.runObject(AstEvaluationEngine.java:65)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runObjectLog(ExecutionUtils.java:304)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.core.eval.AstEvaluationEngine.evaluate(AstEvaluationEngine.java:63)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.model.component.JTableInfo.evaluateColumnModelInvocations(JTableInfo.java:76)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.model.component.JTableInfo.access$0(JTableInfo.java:69)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.model.component.JTableInfo$1.evaluateAfter(JTableInfo.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.broadcast.BroadcastSupport$1.intercept(BroadcastSupport.java:208)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.broadcast.EvaluationEventListener$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$83eb11fe.evaluateAfter()
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.evaluateNode(JavaInfoParser.java:1311)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$1(JavaInfoParser.java:1300)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$ExecutionFlowParseVisitor$3.run(JavaInfoParser.java:602)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runRethrow(ExecutionUtils.java:119)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$ExecutionFlowParseVisitor.postVisit(JavaInfoParser.java:592)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   .....

I opened the Java VisualVM to look what threads is running while freezed:
RMI TCP Accept-0 100%
AWT-Windows 100%
Attach Listener 100%
Signal Dispatcher 100%
Main 100%

And the Heap is playing like crazy, goes up then goes down for every seconds.

Im using Windows 7 Professional with JRE 7 and JDK 7 (Both 64bit, Eclipse 64bit too).

I hope someone have the same problem and knows the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try enlarge your eclipse memory in eclipse.ini add something like

-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

-Xms40m

-Xmx1024m

Comment: That didnt't help, for your answer i only needed to change the Xmx, but on Java VisualVM there was enough Headspace before.

Comment: I already have -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms120m
-Xmx2048m